# strikethrough within equation in jupyter markdown

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

is it possible to strike-through part of an latex equation when using jupyter notebook's markdown? example:

[image]

strike-through the denominator (11-4)! numerator 7!. I've tried using ~~(11-4)!~~ and ~(11-4)!~ which both work on their own but when use them within latex $\frac{11!}{(11-4)!4!}\frac{7!}{(7-4)!4!}$ neither work.

if it matters, I'm running in on Ubuntu.
kindly advise

@osbm this is my output with the code suggest;
[image]

Comment: Your equation has no background and is hard to see/read in dark mode. Just fyi.

Comment: @Dugnom thank you for the input. it is my first time using codecogs to paste the equation as png. are there any suggestions with the settings from codecogs for a layout that is more readable?

Comment: I looked at the tool, and it seems to me the only viable option with it would be to use non-transparent background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use [the MathJax cancel
extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html) you have to add it at the beginning of your markdown cell, like so.

```markdown
$$\require{cancel}$$  

$\frac{11!}{\cancel{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\cancel{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$
```

It provides similar results to the [LaTeX cancel package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cancel).

If you want more flexibility, use [the MathJax enclose extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/enclose.html)

```markdown
$$\require{enclose}$$

$\frac{11!}{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$

$\frac{11!}{\enclose{verticalstrike}{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\enclose{verticalstrike}{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$

$\frac{11!}{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$ this is similar to `\cancel`

$\frac{11!}{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$

$\frac{11!}{\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$
```

The results are:
[image]

In [**this stackexchange post**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you find all the info you need.

Comment: this works out perfectly, thank you for the in-depth explanation and examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\cancel` like this:

```latex
$\frac{11!}{\cancel{(11-4)!}4!}\frac{\cancel{7!}}{(7!-4!)4!}$
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: oh, thats right lemme edit this

Comment: thank you for the reply, i've corrected the equation. however, i've also posted the output with the code you suggested. kindly advise.

Comment: huh, thats weird did you wrap them with brackets? The `\cancel` uses the `cancel` package. Also try `\sout{(11-4)!}` . This one uses a package called `ulem`